# What causes "--- []" in rspec output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm testing content on a page using capybara's have_content syntax:

```
describe "Places page" do
  before { visit places_path }
  it { is_expected.to have_content "Places" }
  it { is_expected.to have_title(full_title('Places')) }
end
```

That code causes this output in the terminal when I run the spec file:

```
.....--- []
.--- []
.
```

Each it block will generate three dashes and brackets "--- []" in the output. The page itself contains an index of Place objects and has an embedded google map. What could cause this and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe the code you test puts this on STDOUT somewhere? Didn't you use `puts` for debugging purposes in your app?

Comment: Exactly that is output of empty YAML array document. May be newar the place of output it is generated by `#to_yml` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer thanks to *Малъ Скрылевъ* and *Marek Lipka*. I grepped for any "puts" in my code or any dependencies. YAMLs [dump_steam](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#method-c-dump_stream) method outputs "--- []"

I was using a gem called [smart_listing](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing) and inside one of the helper methods I found the code:

```
puts args.to_yaml
```

Newer versions of the gem seem to have removed this line. I removed it and "--- []" is gone from my rspec output.